# Why Block351543 is older than Block351542?

Tags: block

I am a little confused here. Why the Age of older Block[351542] is younger than Block[351543]. 
 
Here is the screenshot from blockchain.info

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because blocks are created on different computers. The clock may be slightly different on them. This is not a problem for bitcoin protocol